# PHP Headers already sent - session_start() and setcookie()

Tags: php, header

```
function sec_session_start() {
$session_name = 'exon_id_sessfval';
$secure = false;
$httponly = true;
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); 
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
session_name($session_name);
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
}
```

The following code above generates a headers already sent warning when in relation to session_start() even if I use ob_start() on the first line to try to ignore the problem.

its called on a page like follows:

```
<?php 
include('./inc/sessions.php');
sec_session_start();
header("Location: index.php");
```

Any advice? Of course the header is included in a logical operator to check with a user is logged in, but its not outputting anything. The traceback comes to session_start() so I take it that it has something to do with cookie only sessions.

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /customers/b/2/5/edited.com/httpd.www/beta/login.php:1) in /customers/b/2/5/edited.com/httpd.www/beta/inc/sessions.inc.php on line 11
>
> Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id -
>   headers already sent in
>   /customers/b/2/5/edited.com/httpd.www/beta/inc/sessions.inc.php on
>   line 12
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /customers/b/2/5/edited.com/httpd.www/beta/login.php:1) in
>   /customers/b/2/5/edited.com/httpd.www/beta/login.php on line 13

Comment: You obviously have output above one of your files and could be inside one of your included files. Anything above `<?php` is considered as output. *"Anything"* could be HTML, text, a BOM, even a cookie.

Comment: try to put session_start(); as first as possible in your page

Comment: Something printed before header redirection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obviously have output above one of your files and could be inside one of your included files. Anything above `<?php` is considered as output.

*"Anything"* could be HTML, text, a space, a tab, a BOM ([byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)), even a cookie.

Comment: Yes, thanks. BOM Character it was

Comment: @user1597648 You're welcome and that's what I thought. Also a cookie will also be considered as output, strangely enough.

Comment: @user1597648 If you can accept my answer as the correct one, that way it won't remain as "unanswered". Cheers

Comment: 5 Minutes until I can accept. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I just checked.

I selected Encoding UTF-8 without BOM in Notepad+++ and it solved the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put `ob_start();` at the beginning of your script. It enables **output buffering**, so nothing will be printed until the script finishes (or you flush the buffer manually).

Also remember that **any** character (including spaces, line breaks and stuff like that) is considered output. The first characters of any PHP file need to be `<?php`.